# How can I reset the internal address counter in Giantec GT24C64A EEPROM?

Tags: linux, i2c, eeprom

I'm trying to read from eeprom by using `i2cgert` (or `i2ctransfer`) but i can't reset the internal address counter of the eeprom. Hence, I each time read different values for the same offset.
For example:

```sh
$ i2ctransfer -y 0 w1@0x52 0x00 r20@0x52
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00  

$ i2ctransfer -y 0 w1@0x52 0x00 r20@0x52
0x05 0x00 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x30 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

can you please help me with how i can read with `i2ctransfer` or `i2cget` and to make sure that i starting to read from the beginning of the eeprom?

Comment: Enable driver in the kernel and use it (I assume you are running on Linux?).

Comment: @0andriy Yes but I can't expose it in the dt, so I can't use this method, therefore, I am looking for a script that utilizes i2ctransfer or i2cget to perform this and ensures that it indeed starts from the beginning of the EEPROM.

Comment: Why not?  I don't see anything preventing you from using a proper driver and then you will have just a file somewhere in sysfs that you read, seek, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the internals of `i2ctransfer` although I used it for reading SFP 512 Byte EEPROM and it worked.

Your syntax looks legit, although you dont need chip address specify again:

```
i2ctransfer 0 w1@0x52 0x0 r20
```

this is from DS, how to set the random address first:

> 5.10.2 Random Address Read
> Selective Read operations allow the Master device to select
> at random any memory location for a Read operation. The
> Master device first performs a 'dummy' Write operation by
> sending the Start condition, Slave address and byte
> address of the location it wishes to read. After the
> GT24C64A acknowledges the byte address, the Master
> device resends the Start condition and the Slave address,
> this time with the R/W bit set to one. The EEPROM then
> responds with its ACK and sends the data requested. The
> Master device does not send an ACK but will generate a
> Stop condition. (Refer to Figure 5-9. Random Address Read
> Diagram.)

Did you try 2 separate transfers?
First write dummy byte (set address counter to 0) and then sequential read of 20 bytes.